# C++: Why is std::greater<T>() included in iostream?

Tags: c++

I noticed that my C++ code containing `std::greater<T>()` compiled well without including `<functional>`. This got me thinking. It turns out that this code compiles:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
    std::greater<T>();
}
```

But this one doesn´t:

```
int main(){           //<iostream> doesn´t get included
    std::greater<T>();
}
```

By which I could infer that `<iostream>` contains `std::greater` which seems somewhat odd to me. Can someone explain, why `std::greater<T>()` gets included with `<iostream>`?

I´m using g++ (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-W64 project) 8.1.0 with C++14 if this matters.

Answer (score 3):

it's not guaranteed by ISO standard. The implementation of that header uses it.
You also may find that `<utility>`,`<string>` (may be included as part of `<ios>` or `<iosfwd>`) , `<memory>` and some `<type_traits>` may be available from `<iostream>`.

The five guaranteed headers are (since C++11): ios, iosfwd, istream, ostream, streambuf.

Comment: Is there a flag in g++ to disable this? I think it's bad practice to rely on specific implementations of <iostream> and I would like to  be informed by the compiler when a library doesn't belong to minimum <iostream>.

Comment: @mondlos No, there is no such flag. I'm sorry but that's not compiler's prerogative to programmer from doing something possible. That's part of developer's policy, coding standards of company, etc. If you don't want to rely on it, then don't. You can include header separately, they all are properly guarded.

Comment: @mondlos You probably want a tool like [include-what-you-use](https://include-what-you-use.org/) to analyze the code for you to make it as portable as possible.